# Como exportar um tabela SQL para um arquivo .txt?

Tags: sql, sql-server, txt

bom dia!

Preciso inserir os dados de retorno de um Select em um arquivo .txt contendo os nome das colunas e separando os dados por ";"

Como posso efetuar esse processo?

Grato desde Já

Comment: Crio que esse post te ajudará.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17782033/4312593

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer sua consulta normalmente, depois clica com botão direito do mouse onde está marcado de vermelho na imagem abaixo e salvar como CSV, posteriormente abra o arquivo com notepad, vai estar com headers e separado por ";" como abaixo.

```
IDT_CLIENTE;COD_COMERC;COD_FILIAL;IND_WHITE_LABEL_ATIVO
1;4236304;5556251;NULL
2;4464027;5556452;NULL
20;4261114;5556255;1
22;4236304;5556252;0
24;4503199;5556553;0
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Ou então você pode ir pelo wizard:
- botão direito no banco
- tasks
- export data...
- na origem, seleciona SQL Server Native Client (última opção)
- no destino, flat file destination, coloca o caminho desejado, assinala se Unicode ou não, é opcional colocar um qualificador (por exemplo, todos os campos iniciam e terminam com aspas)
- copy data...
- selecione a tabela, informe o delimitador da linha (geralmente é o CR LF) e por último o delimitador da coluna (no seu caso, semicolon)
 - finish